# Correctness of JMH Benchmark to compare Collections.synchronizedList vs CopyOnWriteArrayList performance

Tags: java, collections, concurrency, jmh

I'm trying to compare performance of `Collections.synchronizedList` versus  `CopyOnWriteArrayList` with multiple readers and writers.

Benchmark code:

```java
    @Fork(1)
    @State(Scope.Group)
    @Warmup(iterations = 5)
    @Meansurement(iterations = 3)
    public class CopyOnWriteVsSynchronizedList {

        public List<String> synchronizedList;
        public List<String> list;

        @Setup
        public void init() {
            List<String> theList = new ArrayList<>();
            Random random = new Random();
            for (int i = 0; i < 5000; i++) {
                theList.add(Long.toString(random.nextLong()));
            }
            synchronizedList = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<>(theList));
            list = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<>(theList);
        }

        @Benchmark
        @Group
        @GroupThreads(10)
        public String readSyncList() {
            return synchronizedList.get(1567);
        }

        @Benchmark
        @Group
        @GroupThreads(10)
        public void addSyncList() {
            synchronizedList.add("6854985168049806540");
        }

        @Benchmark
        @Group
        @GroupThreads(10)
        public void insertSyncList() {
            synchronizedList.add(1521, "8498765468564564564");
        }

        @Benchmark
        @Group
        @GroupThreads(10)
        public void updateSyncList() {
            synchronizedList.set(1433, "4879465132156489944");
        }

        @Benchmark
        @Group("copyGroup")
        @GroupThreads(10)
        public String readList() {
            return list.get(1567);
        }

        @Benchmark
        @Group("copyGroup")
        @GroupThreads(10)
        public void addList() {
            list.add("6854985168049806540");
        }

        @Benchmark
        @Group("copyGroup")
        @GroupThreads(10)
        public void insertList() {
            list.add(1521, "8498765468564564564");
        }

        @Benchmark
        @Group("copyGroup")
        @GroupThreads(10)
        public void updateList() {
            list.set(1433, "4879465132156489944");
        }
    }
```

This benchmark executed a very long time. I have this results on `Intel Core i5-4570 @ 3.2 GHz`, `Windows 7 64-bit`, `8 GB RAM`:

```
Benchmark                                            Mode  Cnt          Score   Error  Units
CopyOnWriteVsSynchronizedList.copyGroup             thrpt       966141680,668          ops/s
CopyOnWriteVsSynchronizedList.copyGroup:addList     thrpt           38348,240          ops/s
CopyOnWriteVsSynchronizedList.copyGroup:insertList  thrpt           39274,967          ops/s
CopyOnWriteVsSynchronizedList.copyGroup:readList    thrpt       958988509,918          ops/s
CopyOnWriteVsSynchronizedList.copyGroup:updateList  thrpt         7075547,542          ops/s
CopyOnWriteVsSynchronizedList.group                 thrpt           23004,619          ops/s
CopyOnWriteVsSynchronizedList.group:addSyncList     thrpt             312,534          ops/s
CopyOnWriteVsSynchronizedList.group:insertSyncList  thrpt           21677,896          ops/s
CopyOnWriteVsSynchronizedList.group:readSyncList    thrpt              53,375          ops/s
CopyOnWriteVsSynchronizedList.group:updateSyncList  thrpt             960,815          ops/s
```

Is this benchmark correct?  Thanks for help.

Comment: Throughput looks very good IMO. Try to measure `init`, maybe that's what is taking all the time?

Comment: This comparsion is illegal. I create custom List implementation with ReentrantReadWriteLock and getted worst performance than Collections.synchronizedList, because it is impossible to predict which thread the OS scheduler will give more execution time :(